# Can I create a Django object using a subquery for a field value?

Tags: python, django, orm, race-condition

### TLDR

When creating a new object using Django ORM, can I, in a transactionally safe / race-condition-free manner, set a field's value based on an already existing object's value, say `F('sequence_number') + 1` where `F('sequence_number')` refers not to the current object (which does not exist yet) but to the most recent object with that prefix in the table?

### Longer version

I have a model `Issue` with properties `sequence_number` and `sequence_prefix`. There is a unique constraint on `(sequence_prefix, sequence_number)` (e.g. `DATA-1`).

```py
class Issue(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    sequence_prefix = models.CharField(blank=True, default="", max_length=32)
    sequence_number = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["sequence_prefix", "sequence_number"], name="unique_sequence"
            )
        ]
```

The idea is that issues —for auditing purposes— have unique sequence numbers for each variable (user-determined) prefix: when creating an issue the user selects a prefix, e.g. `REVIEW` or `DATA`, and the sequence number is the incremented value of the previous issue with that same sequence. So it's like an `AutoField` but dependent on the value of *another* field for its value. There can *not* be two issues `DATA-1`, but `REVIEW-1` and `DATA-1` and `OTHER-1` all may exist at the same time.

How can I tell Django when creating an Issue, that it must find the most recent object for that given `sequence_prefix`, take the `sequence_number + 1` and use that for the new object's sequence_number value, in a way that is safe of any race-condition?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to archive this is to override the `save()` method of the `Issue` model.

For example:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    sequence_prefix = models.CharField(blank=True, default="", max_length=32)
    sequence_number = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        max_id_by_prefix = Issue.objects.filter(sequence_prefix=self.sequence_prefix).max().id
        self.sequence_number = max_id_by_prefix + 1
        super(Issue, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=["sequence_prefix", "sequence_number"], name="unique_sequence"
            )
        ]
```

In this way, before saving the object, you can take the max `sequence_number` of the `sequence_prefix` that you are saving.

Comment: Hi Myth, thanks for your answer. I considered that, but I believe this is vulnerable to a race condition: if, while saving, some other user creates an issue with that same prefix after the first line of your `save` is executed, the value of `max_id_by_prefix` will no longer be the maximum. So when I insert "my" issue, `sequence_number` (which is `max_id_by_prefix + 1`) will be equal to an issue _already_ in the database, and will then fail the unique constraint.

This is why I'm looking for a way to query for and insert a value within the same SQL statement, preventing such a race condition

Comment: Uhm nice point. Did you evaluate to use the get_or_create? In this case if the query return a creation you can continue. Otherwise you can update the value ovoiding the race cond

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work — you would need to query for the `latest sequence_number` _before_ doing to the `get_or_create`, and then you'd just have the same race condition, no?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use database sequences (AutoField), I believe you will need to implement something on your own. There are two options

1. Prevent concurrent inserts per specific sequence_prefix with some locking mechanism (I would use Redis for a distributed lock, to support multi-processing setup)
2. Implement your own sequencing (again, Redis is a perfect choices), which will provide you with auto-incrementing sequence_number per prefix. For example:
   `sequence_number = redis_client.incr('sequence:REVIEW')`